# Add "onclick" option to header menu item

Tags: menus, jquery, javascript, headers

on my website I have a problem.
In my menù I have a voice called "area riservata".

What I want to do is: insert a condition on this specific voice, so when a user click on this voice a not logged-in user will go to a page ( called "diventa Yallers" where they can register on my site ) and a logged-in user will go to another page ( called "profilo", where users can see their profile settings etc ).

Comment: Share some code so we can see what the menu structure is like.  It should be reasonably straightforward using the is_current_user() function to output conditional jQuery that re-routes the user.

Comment: This is the header's code: https://pastebin.com/3U10tiT7

Comment: That doesn't show any indication as to what the menu structure is like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the GeneratePress site and looked at one of their demos:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation sub-menu-left" itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" itemscope>
    <div class="inside-navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="mobile-menu">Menu</span>
        </button>
        <div id="primary-menu" class="main-nav">
            <ul id="menu-menu-1" class=" menu sf-menu">

                <li id="menu-item-594520" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-594520"><a href="https://generatepress.com/">area riservata</a></li>

                <li id="menu-item-594521" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-594521"><a href="https://generatepress.com/premium/">Premium</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .inside-navigation -->
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

So in your function's PHP you can try dropping this:

```
function change_area_riservata_url() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
            <?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                var hrefAtt = 'https://google.com'; //the URL if user is logged in
            <?php else : ?>
                var hrefAtt = 'https://bing.com'; //the URL if NOT logged in
            <?php endif; ?>
            //Make sure the correct ID is in place
            $( '#menu-item-594520 a' ).attr( 'href', hrefAtt );
        } );
    </script>
} ?>
add_action( 'generate_after_header', 'change_area_riservata_url', 20 );
```

Obviously you'll want to edit the URLs and the ID of the menu item so that it matches your site.

Comment: Just tried it, it works!

Comment: Fantastic. Glad it's all sorted. :-)